# で as an Agent Marker

Tags: particle-で

I read a study that listed the Agent Markers in Japanese as Ga, Ni, Kara, and De

I currently have this understanding of agent marking in Japanese:

GA = Active Sentences
NI = Passive Sentences
DE = ?
KARA = Passive (No Physical Contact)

Can anyone fill me in on when exactly De marks the agent?  I've definitely heard it before, but I have no idea why it is being chosen over the other options.

Agent marking just being the one actually doing the action.

Comment: Can you provide an example of such a sentence? I have never really heard one

Comment: The study cites this sentence:
Ato wa watashi-tachi DE yarimasu.
We will do the rest.

Answer (score 2):

で covers a broad range of circumstances under which some action is taken or some event happens, including but not limited to place, means, and cause. You can understand this で as denoting one concerning the people involved in the action (as agents). These are usually a group of people. You can say 私達でする but not 私でする. You can say 私の方でする but this should be understood as "my side" as opposed to other parties although 私 may be the only constituent of that "side".

The difference from が is it's still about a circumstance, or condition, surrounding the action and doesn't answer the question *who does it?* as directly. The question it answers is more like *involving whom?* or *under whose responsibility?*. Probably for this reason it has no sense of exclusion unless the existence of an opposing party is assumed as in scenarios where division of responsibilities is at issue. 私の方でする is one such example, and it practically means the same as 私がする (not anyone else). 皆でする excludes no one. In contrast,  皆がする excludes anyone who falls outside of the boundaries of 皆, sometimes even 私, because it specifically answers *who does it?*

Comment: When I read this answer yesterday the distinction between 皆がする and 皆でする made a lot of sense, and through that I thought I understood your point about clusivity. 私でする being invalid seemed very important. But it just occurred to me there's also phrases like 自分で言うのもなんだが and 自分が言うのもなんだが where で、が appear to be interchangeable, with the で version seemingly more popular? Here で is used to commonly refer to one person instead of a group of people. I wonder if a similar distinction can be made. I wonder if the distinction can explain why それ自分で言う？ is fine, but それ自分が言う？ seems much rarer if not invalid

Comment: @EddieKal - 自分が言うのも〜 is like saying it's weird (for the lack of a better translation for なん) that the person saying this is me (not anyone else), or perhaps more idiomatically it's weird that this is coming from me. This 自分 is a substitute for 私. It directly refers to the first person. 自分で言うのも〜 is more like it's weird that I'm saying this for my own sake. This 自分 reflexively references whoever is the subject, as "self", which happens to be 私 in this case.

Comment: 自分で言う is said as opposed to 他の人に言ってもらう. The question is not really about *who* says it as asked when it's already known or assumed that someone says it. I don't know how to explain this, but it's more "circumstantial" and adverbially works on the action. Its singularity doesn't prevent the use of で. (Nor does that of ひとり, by the way.)

Answer (score -1):

The example sentence you provided あとは私達でやります is just treating  私達 as the method of the action. Literally: we'll do by "using" ourselves". I can't tell for sure if that can be considered the agent of the action in japanese, but it becomes the agent especially when translating to english. You should check if the study you're reading is japanese or western. If we said パソコンでやります the computer wouldn't be agent nor the subject. But I don't know if japanese grammar considers individuals with the method particle as the agent.

Comment: Semantically speaking, I think in both English & Japanese the example provided for De being the agent marker would be understood as "We" being the agent.  As for the example you provided, in both English & Japanese Pasokon would be understood as an instrument.  De has multiple role in Japanese semantically, but I'm not quite sure when it can be used while not sounding weird from a native speaker's perspective.

And all I mean by semantics is like what actually happens.  It's like how Ga is both an Agent Marker in Active Sentences, but an Object marker in passive sentences.

Comment: I don't think that's how passive voice works.  田中さんにケーキが食べられた GA expresses the subject and NI expresses the passive agent. It's not different from active sentences. There's no object in that sentence. "The cake was eaten by Tanaka". What I meant by translation is, for example, 私達でやりました a foreigner could translate it as "**we** did it" and that would maybe be the reason why that resource was considering it be an agent marker. In other cases that で is being used with objects, yes, the assumed is that you're talking yourself or a group you are part of.

Comment: The thing is that I don't know if japanese grammar considers sentences like 私達でやりました as the agent or just an adverbial adjunct like in english. My guess is that the op's source is western.

Comment: Hmm, if I'm not incorrect, I don't believe Subjects have semantic value.  For example, English "The dog bit the man" and "The man was bit by the dog" have differing subjects, but identical semantics.  The dog is the subject in the first, but the man is the subject in the second.  Semantically, the agent in both is the dog, and if we go by thematic roles we can say the man is the "Theme" of both sentences or the entity that directly receives the action.  To me, subject is more so a matter of perspective.

Comment: If you asked a Japanese person, in the sentence "私達でやりました" who やりました'd they'd certainly say 私達 which means that semantically 私達 is the agent.  I'm more so interested in the situations or feeling that this type of agent marking has over the same sentence, but with particle Ga "私達がやりました".

Comment: Oh. I didn't understand that your question was about the nuance. Semantically, they both are "who does it" but the focus is totally different. The answer is simpler than you might think.  "どうやってそんなに重い荷物を持ち出せたの?""皆で持ち出したんだ！".誰があのすごいケーキを作ったの?私達が作った！ で emphasizes the method and が just shows the subject.

Comment: "but an Object marker in passive" is the part I corrected you. There's no object. Classical grammar just categorizes it that way. The meanings of those sentences are not really the same. The difference is on the emphasis although you understand the basic same thing from them.